# What version of Angular does ionic v. 1.0.0 use?

Tags: ionic-framework

I couldn't find this in a google search, or even on the ionic website, and it was in an obscure part of the ionic files, so when I found it finally, I thought I'd make this question here and answer it so other people out there don't have to encounter the hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is..... Ionic V.1.0.0 uses angular V.1.3.13.